# PC wakes from sleep, when i plug in laptop to the same power strip the PC is plugged into

Tags: power

It has happened multiple times. The PC has gone to sleep, but when i plug in the charging cable to the laptop, the PC wakes up.

My rig is:
 - PSU: Cooler Master RS-460-PSAP-I3

- MB: Gigabyte GA-P110-D3
- CPU: INTEL CORE i5 6400

Any ideas on why it happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As asked the question is very broad, but since I find one answer rather scary I am going to answer anyway:

It only seems to make sense it the OC is set to power up after power loss **and** the laptops charges has such a big inrush of power when plugged in that it drops the voltage from the wall to close to zero.

A brief, limited drop is normal when you plug in a new device. A significant, longer drop which is big enough to briefly starve other devices of power is not.

Which leads me to these two possible conclusions:

1. The circuit you are plugging in is already near its maximum capacity. When you plug in the charger is briefly surpassed what it can handle. Not a good thing. (What else is plugged into that powerstrip?)
2. Or the chargers has a much bigger inrush than is normal. If you have a second identical charger and this one does not trigger the same behavious then worry. Optionally throw away the laptop charger and get a new one.

You should be able to test both of these with a generic voltage meter, a UPS which records voltages (probably not if you only have a basic UPS) or a power strip with voltage/amp/power used capabilities. And ofcourse you check the PCs setting in its firmware (UEFI or BIOS).

Try to measure at least the following this:

- Potential difference/voltage with nothing plugged in. (e.g. 240v)
- Potential difference/voltage with all devices plugged in and power up (may drop a little, but not significantly)
- Potential difference/voltage at the moment you plug in the charger.

Comment: The reasoning is correct, but it is typical and normal for chargers to have a high peak current when plugged in. They are creating DC voltage, and for that they have a big capacity, which takes a peak current when connected to voltage.

Comment: I know they have an inrush current, but big enough to drop voltage below the PSU's treshhold off -unplugged-plugged_in_again-boot_after_powerloss? That seems excessive for a normal environment.. I guess I should have asked what the normal power lvels are. Maybe this is from an already stressed circuit.

Comment: Yes. We don't know what else is already plugged in on that circuit.

Comment: Power up and resume from sleep are different, since they say it "wakes up" I assume it is resuming from sleep, this would not happen if voltage dropped below threshold where the PC would automatically power up after a power cut. This auto power up can be disabled in the bios to verify it is resuming from sleep and not actually powering up from a power cut.

Comment: I think the problem is with the power strip. It has caught on fire before when too much power was used from it. Maybe the metal bars in it have too much resistance. I will replace it, and report back.